# Unloading a shared library from memory

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I am trying to modify this shared library (with .so) extension on Linux. I am inserting some printf statement and fprintf statement to debug, and it has no effect. I removed the .so file and realized that the the program still runs fine. Does it mean that the program is loaded into memory?? (But I'm sure only the program I'm testing for uses that .so file though)

How do I get it to unload so I can make sure my program is loading the modified one?

Comment: You don't give enough details, so we have to guess what you are really doing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, shared libraries are not cached in memory. If you have deleted the `.so` file and your program still runs, then either:

- the program is loading an `.so` of the same name from a different location, or
- the program can run without loading the `.so`

If the `.so` is supposed to be loaded at program startup, then you can use `ldd` to find out where your OS thinks the `.so` actually is.

If the `.so` is loaded dynamically at runtime, then perhaps `strace` will be able to help pinpoint what is happening.

Comment: By startup do you mean the program startup or the OS startup?

Comment: Program startup. ELF executables contain a list of shared libraries that the OS loads on behalf of the process when the process starts. The process may elect to open more shared libraries later using `dlopen()`.

Comment: It's a python program that uses the shared library, kind of making things more complicated.

Comment: From the OS point of view, it's all the same. Python will be using `dlopen()` to load the library. Perhaps run it under `strace` and capture all the output, then search for the name of your `.so` in the trace.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I have used `strace`. Apparently it's loading things from multiple places (around 5 or 6), and the build script of that project did put up multiple copy of the so, although it's not apparent to the user during `make install`.

Answer (score 4):

You can read `/proc/1234/maps` to find out the memory map of process 1234. This also shows the dynamically loaded shared objects.

You may use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to change the path of shared libraries and `ldconfig` to upgrade its cache. Look also in `/etc/ld.so.conf` etc.

Of course, you have to restart the program loading your shared library.